# Create SetupIntent whithout payment and charge the split amount later two seperate times

Tags: stripe-payments

So we wanted to integrate Stripe into our travel booking system. After corresponding with Stripe we had an approach recommended which we implemented.

Important is the following:

1. Customer does a booking and after the booking he has the possibility to enter his payment data
2. The payment is separated into two, Down and final payment, like 40% and 60% or something like that.
3. These two payments do NOT get triggered immediately but later when the travel is checked and everything is ok
4. They get triggered separately. Down payment a few days after booking and final payment days after that

What we made for that is:

1. An SetupIntent that captures the payment data
2. And events that get triggered when (days later) down and finally payments are being charged manually in the backend of the app
3. These Events trigger an paymentIntents with `off_session` set to `true`

All of that works fine, but the issue is that the payment interface, where the customer enters his credit card data, always shows an amount of 0 (zero).
Stripe told us that is expected because at SetupIntend stage no payment is made, but we cannot communicate an 0 amount to the customers and later charge them twice.
Stripe says we need to communicate that in our own GUI. Of course we do that, but still it's an unacceptable approach.

After we told that Stripe suggested these two approaches without other options:

- Use PaymentIntents:

  - Create a payment intent with capture manual for the total amount of the two payments and then capture the total amount
  - Do a first payment and save the PaymentMethod, then achieve another payment attempt off session

But none of these work for us because we need two separate charges, and none of them can be done immediately.